# what is the radius of convergence of the Laurent series for $sin(1/z)$ centered at $z = 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Also, what kind of isolated singularity does this function have at $ = 0$?

I was able to find the desired Laurent series by taking the power series for $sin(z)$ and replacing the argument with $\frac{1}{z}$.

$\sin(z) = z - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^5}{5!} - ... \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} + ... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

So

$\sin(\frac{1}{z}) = \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{(3!)z^3} + \frac{1}{(5!)z^5} - ... \frac{1}{(2n+1)!z^{2n+1}} + ... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nz^{-(2n+1})}{(2n+1)!}$

However, I'm not sure how to find the radius of convergence here.  I want to say that it's infinite, since the $z$ is in the denominator.

Also, what about the singularity at $z=0$?  Since this is a trig function and trig functions are defined in terms of exponentials, I want to say that this will have an essential singularity, but I'm not sure how to back up my claim.

Answer (score 2):

The radius of convergence of $sin(w)$ is infinity, i.e. converges $\forall w \in \mathbb{C}$. Take $w = \frac{1}{z} \in \mathbb{C}$, obviously $z \ne 0$. Then $sin(\frac{1}{z})$ converges for $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: 0 < |z|\}$.

Futhermore $sin(\frac{1}{z})=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n z^{-(2n+1)}}{(2n+1)!}$ is the Laurent Expansion of $sin(\frac{1}{z})$.

(Corollary 1.18 p.109 Function of One Complex Variable (2nd edition) - John B. Conway) -

Let $z = a$ be an isolated singularity of $f$ and let $f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n(z-a)^n$ be its Laurent Expansion in $ann(a; 0, R)$. Then:

(c) $z=a$ is an essential singularity iff $a_n \ne 0$ for infinitely many negative integers n.

Thus, $z=0$ is an essential singularity.